# What does the "Certificates" section in seahorse do?

Tags: gpg, certificates, libreoffice, signature, seahorse

What does the "Certificates" / "System Trust" section of seahorse do?

[image: Seahorse Certificates System Trust]

I am [trying to sign a document in LibreOffice](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/224355/no-certificates-show-up-when-trying-to-sign-a-document/) and the menu there uses the word "Certificate", so I am thinking that I need to have something here. I already have my GPG key imported into the "PGP Keys" -> "GnuPG keys" menu and its trust is set to ultimate.

Is there a way I can make the system trust the key or make the key into a certificate so that I can use it to sign my document? Or is this part of the menu for something completely different (if so, how do I get LibreOffice to use my GPG key?).

Comment: The "Certificates" tab there is for X.509 not PGP, so you shouldn't expect anything there. Two questions though: did you open LibreOffice before or after adding your key to Seahorse? (That may or may not make a difference) And is the file you want to sign saved to disk? (It has to be)

Comment: I tried re-opening LibreOffice several times and also restarting my computer. Yes, it is saved.